# AWS CLI command to list down all the images used by all the nodes in a AWS EKS Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing, aws-cli, amazon-eks

I want an AWS CLI command to list down all the images used by all the nodes in a AWS EKS Cluster. We can use kubectl to list down images used to spin up a container. But I want AWS CLI command to list down all the images used to spin up all the nodes in a AWS EKS Cluster.

I tried to find similiar kubectl command but after many research I and not finding anything, I am looking for AWS CLI command.